# ConstraintLayout - When text wrapping happens, it will "push away" ImageView. How to avoid such behavior?

Tags: android

I have the following layout

[image]

I wish to achieve

1. Available space priority will be given to red region `LinearLayout`, so that no text wrapping will occur.
2. `ConstraintLayout` will try its best effort to occupy remaining space. If the remaining space isn't enough, it will perform text wrapping.

Hence,

1. `wrap_content` is given to red region `LinearLayout`
2. `android:layout_width="0dp"` and `android:layout_weight="1"` is given to `ConstraintLayout`

---

However, currently, when the content of `ConstraintLayout` is too long. It will perform text wrapping. However, it will also perform an undesired effect. **It will push away the baby icon**

[image]

This is my complete XML

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"

    android:id="@+id/top_relative_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="12dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/sticky_image_view"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/sticky_image_view"

            android:text="Home long text long text"
            android:id="@+id/label_text_view"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingEnd="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:textColor="?attr/secondaryTextColor" />

        <ImageView
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/label_text_view"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/label_text_view"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

            android:id="@+id/sticky_image_view"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:tint="?attr/greyIconColor"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/sn_baby" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#ff0000"

        android:gravity="top"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pin_image_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd"
            android:src="?attr/smallPinIcon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/locked_image_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/reminder_repeat_image_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingEnd="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/reminder_image_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingEnd="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Yesterday, 31 December, 2019"
            android:id="@+id/date_time_text_view"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="?attr/secondaryTextColor" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

---

Any idea how I can prevent such?

Comment: "Yesterday, 31 December 2019" is a `TextView`. Please look at the posted layout XML.

Comment: Is there any restriction to use ConstraintLayout as base layout, instead of LinearLayout?

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want the text to wrap, you might want to constrain the sticky_image_view to the end, bottom and top of parent. Then just add either a height or width to this imageview, a ratio of 1:1, and a horizontalBias of 0. This should do the trick.

Comment: That doesn't help. Can you kindly post a complete XML?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `layout_width = "0dp"` on `ConstraintLayout`'s `TextView`. `ConstraintLayout` constraints work when you set dimension to `0dp`.

And the image view should be like this -

```
<ImageView
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

Instead of this -

```
<ImageView
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/label_text_view"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/label_text_view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

Comment: That doesn't help. Can you kindly post a complete XML?

Comment: Not working for long text case - https://i.imgur.com/iky3QLw.png (Text crop), or short text case - https://i.imgur.com/UVHSDnk.png (Not aligned to left)

Comment: You can set gravity left to the TextView? And you can try to use margin instead of padding.

Comment: Looking the image you shared, it's look like the Home textview width is still wrap_content.

Comment: "Try to set layout_width = "0dp" on ConstraintLayout's TextView" -> This will push baby icon to right most even the the TextView text is short.

Comment: Then you need to remove these lines from the textview and keep the image view as before.  app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/sticky_image_view"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/sticky_image_view"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this layout can work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/top_relative_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="12dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:paddingEnd="28dp"
            android:text="Home"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/sticky_image_view"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/label_text_view"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/label_text_view"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_done" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pin_image_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_circle" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/locked_image_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/reminder_repeat_image_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:paddingEnd="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/reminder_image_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:paddingEnd="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date_time_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Yesterday, 31 December, 2019"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: No. If the TextView becomes more than 1 line, the drawable will not stick to the top anymore. The drawable will be vertical center, which is not what I want.

Comment: I've updated the layout with the ImageView sticky on top

Comment: Sorry. Still no. Adding `android:layout_weight="1"` in TextView will handle text wrapping problem. But, If the text is short, the baby icon should be near to text. It should look exactly like my first screenshot. Right now, for text is short case, `android:layout_weight="1"` in TextView will cause the baby icon pushed to right most.

Comment: This is the undesired effect - https://i.imgur.com/2wRtKwP.png, after using `android:layout_weight="1"` in TextView technique.